# How to use random.choice() in a list without a specific element?

Tags: python

Im currently writing a very simplified version of the board game Clue. I have a question on how to present new clues to the user.
The code has a list called clew_list which has all of the characters and guns available. The new clue is chosen randomly using random.choice(clue_list). My doubt is how to implement that function without taking into consideration the actual crime, which is also an element of clue_list.
The Crime is also chosen randomly using classes and the same method mentioned earlier.
Thank you

Comment: A sample input and expected output would be nice, but you can create a copy of the list first that excludes the actual crime.

Comment: This is way too vague to answer. Can you actually try to do what you want to do, and if you have trouble, post a [MCVE], including sample inputs and outputs, so we have a clue what the goal is?

Comment: Aren't these independent choices? You could use a list per type of thing. Shuffle them each and then use pop() for each selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new list and pick randomly in the new list

```
random.choice([element for clew_list in agents if !(isinstance(element, crime))])
```

Comment: I implemented that and it worked! Thank you very much

Comment: Happy coding nacho

Answer (score 0):

You can have a while loop until you get what you were looking for. Might seem like a more rudimentary solution compared to the solution made by RCvaram, but if you agents list is big then the probability of picking the wrong thing goes down, and also creating a new list is pretty slow.

```
choice = random.choice(agents)
while !(isinstance(choice, crime):
   choice = random.choice(agents)
```